# gnome-terminal not in executable format in Lazarus

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I just installed Lazarus for an algorithms course on uni on my Ubuntu PC.

I'm experiencing the following error when I try to run a console application over the terminal.

> "/usr/bin/gnome-terminal": not in executable format: file format not
> recognized

The Launching application on Run Parameters is setup like this:

> /usr/bin/gnome-terminal -t 'Lazarus Run Output' -e
> '$(LazarusDir)/tools/runwait.sh $(TargetCmdLine)'

When I do `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` in any terminal, I get a new terminal popping out, so I'm not sure why it isn't working.

I just want to output the run to something to see if my code is working.

Comment: gnome-terminal is probably a script or a symlink, and the launcher doesn't recognize it.

Comment: You can also try another terminal emulator, often you find xterm. Try to find one (a real plain executable) in /usr/bin: as Marco says, the launcher can find it difficult to launch esoteric scripts/symlinks/whatever.

Comment: but /usr/bin/gnome-terminal can't be a symlink. Otherwise, how can i find the correct path for it?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if your question is still relevant to you at this point, but I came across the same problem and ended up by following the advice on the wiki:

https://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/IDE_Window:_Run_parameters#Launching_application

So, I installed xterm with apt-get, entered `/usr/bin/xterm $(TargetCmdLine)` in Run > Run Parameters > Launching Application, and it worked.